# Next JS: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom hook in my Nextjs application to send a request using Axios.

Here is my `useApiRequest` file:

```js
import { ErrorResponse, SuccessResponse } from "@/types/api";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const useApiRequest = <T>(
  httpMethod: string,
  url: string,
  data?: any
): [boolean, T | string, string] => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<[boolean, T | string, string]>([
    false,
    "",
    "",
  ]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const apiResponse: AxiosResponse<SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse> =
        await axios({
          method: httpMethod,
          url: url,
          data: data,
        });

      if ("result" in apiResponse.data && "message" in apiResponse.data) {
        const successData: SuccessResponse<T> = apiResponse.data;
        setResponse([true, successData.result, successData.message]);
      } else {
        const errorData: ErrorResponse = apiResponse.data;
        setResponse([false, errorData.error, errorData.error]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        setResponse([false, "", error.message]);
      } else {
        setResponse([false, "", "Terjadi kesalahan"]);
      }
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  return response;
};

export default useApiRequest;
```

I have used that hook in one of my pages like this:

```
import Button from "@/components/elements/buttons/Button";
import useApiRequest from "@/hooks/useApiRequest";
import Head from "next/head";

const JadwalPage = () => {
  const handleLogin = () => {
    const [isSuccess, responseData, message] = useApiRequest(
      "post",
      "/auth/login",
      {
        username: "admin",
        password: "pratama-putra",
      }
    );

    if (isSuccess) {
      console.log("Data berhasil diperoleh:", responseData);
    } else {
      console.error("Gagal melakukan permintaan:", message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen">
      <Head>
        <title>Jadwal Karyawan</title>
      </Head>
      <Button onClick={handleLogin}>Click me</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default JadwalPage;
```

Why do I always get an error `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

I tried to change `useApiRequest` from an arrow function to a regular function, but it still produces the same error.

Comment: You can not use hooks inside a function. Try moving it to the top of your component.

Comment: https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning Here are the details for invalid hook calls. You can find a reference for how to not use a hook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use use Hooks at the top level of your React function. From the React documentation-

> Hooks are JavaScript functions, but you need to follow two rules when using them.
> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components. ✅ Call Hooks from custom
> Hooks

[Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

Answer (score 0):

It’s not supported to call Hooks (functions starting with use) in any other cases, for example:

- Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.
- Do not call Hooks after a conditional return statement.
- Do not call Hooks in event handlers.
- Do not call Hooks in class components.
- Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or
  useEffect.

You should use your hook at the top level of your component. You can create behaviour like mutation. So whenever you call a hook it will return a function which can be further used to make API calls.

```js
import { ErrorResponse, SuccessResponse } from "@/types/api";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const useApiRequest = <T>(
  httpMethod: string,
  url: string,
  data?: any
): [boolean, T | string, string] => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<[boolean, T | string, string]>([
    false,
    "",
    "",
  ]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const apiResponse: AxiosResponse<SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse> =
        await axios({
          method: httpMethod,
          url: url,
          data: data,
        });

      if ("result" in apiResponse.data && "message" in apiResponse.data) {
        const successData: SuccessResponse<T> = apiResponse.data;
        setResponse([true, successData.result, successData.message]);
      } else {
        const errorData: ErrorResponse = apiResponse.data;
        setResponse([false, errorData.error, errorData.error]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        setResponse([false, "", error.message]);
      } else {
        setResponse([false, "", "Terjadi kesalahan"]);
      }
    }
  };

  return {
    fetchData,
    response
  };
};

export default useApiRequest;
```

Use it like below:

```js
import Button from "@/components/elements/buttons/Button";
import useApiRequest from "@/hooks/useApiRequest";
import Head from "next/head";

const JadwalPage = () => {
  // Use hook at top level
  const { fetchData, response } = useApiRequest(
      "post",
      "/auth/login",
      {
        username: "admin",
        password: "pratama-putra",
      }
    );
    

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    // Call your API 
    await fetchData();

    // Use/Process your data 

  }
```